# Why do we look only for the first and second derivative when dealing with diffusions?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

I would like to understand, from an analytical point of view, why is it that we only take the first and second derivatives into account when computing the generator of a diffusion. This question is based on the following argument, to be found in Petr Mandl's book: Analytical treatment of one dimensional Markov processes  page 12

[image]

[image]

In the proof of equation (20) the author expands only until the second order and then used the continuity of $f''$ Why didn't he go further and considered $f'''(\zeta(y))$. Or else, why didn't he stop before and just considered the first derivative, $f'(\zeta(y))$?

Comment: I haven't read the full thing, but this screams to me quadratic variation. Basically with Brownian motion $(dW(t))^2=dt$ and $(dW(t))^3=0$. So when you Taylor expand generators with Brownian motion, higher derivatives have a $(dW(t))^3$ and thus disappear. This may or may not be relevant. let me read more.

Comment: yes, exactly. This is reasoning along the lines of Itô. What is the translation of this property in terms of the transition probability. This must be hidden somewhere. It seems to me that it will be something like $$\lim_{t \to 0}t^{-1} \int (y-x)^n\, P(t,x;dy)= 0, \quad n>2$$